# what code to use when using visual c++ 6.0

Tags: c, visual-c++-6

I've compiled and executed the following c code in borland c++ compiler. It works in it perfectly but it is not working in visual c++ 6.0 compiler. what changes are to be made to make it work in visual c++ 6.0 ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char buffer[256] = {0};
    char password[] = "password";
    char c;
    int pos = 0;

    printf("%s", "Enter password: ");
    do {
        c = getch();

          if( isprint(c) )
        {
            buffer[ pos++ ] = c;
            printf("%c", '*');
        }
        else if( c == 8 && pos )
          {
            buffer[ --pos ] = '\0';
            printf("%s", "\b \b");
        }
     } while( c != 13&& pos < 256 );

    if( !strcmp(buffer, password) )
        printf("\n%s\n", "Logged on succesfully!");
    else
        printf("\n%s\n", "Incorrect login!");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: If using C++, why don't use `<iostream>` and stream overloaded operators `>>` and `<<`?

Comment: @Benoit It's a C program, though. She's just using a C++ compiler.

Comment: @Rae Kettler: sorry, I didn't see that.

Comment: @peoro: actually, when u type in  the password, it should appear as '*****' but in visual c++ compiler, its not even able to take the input.

Comment: I'm wondering why you are reading the input character by character instead of just using `scanf` or `fgets`.

Comment: Does conio.h (an ancient and unstandard header, comes with getch) even exist on VC++?

Comment: @Lara I just copied your program into VC6 it runs and works.  Are you getting any other errors?

Comment: @mark: did u do any changes??

Comment: @Lara No I just copied it directly.

Comment: @Lara I created a new Win32 Console Application with an empty project. I then added a new C++ source file called main and pasted your code into it and ran it.

Comment: Why are you using VC++ 6.0?  That version was released in 1998 (!).  Why don't you use a more modern version, such as 2008 (aka 9.0) or 2010 (aka 10.0)?

Answer (score 0):

vc 6, does not support conio.
Remove the include.

getch will not do what you expect it to do.

Look into building a [console app](http://www.mcc-us.com/c4ipfaq.htm) under vc6.